# Saving an html5 canvas without a cursor image

Tags: javascript, html, save, easeljs

I have been using EaselJS code for my html5 canvas that I have been developing. I added a save function to the canvas. When I save my image using the .toDataURL variable the cursor image appears on the saved image. I was hoping there is a way to make the cursor transparent, or a code that keeps the cursor image from appearing in my saveImage function.

**The cursor draw code**

```
function handleMouseMove(event) {
cursor.x = stage.mouseX;
cursor.y = stage.mouseY;

        if (!isDrawing) {
            stage.update();
            return;
        }

        var midPoint = new createjs.Point(oldPt.x + stage.mouseX>>1, oldPt.y+stage.mouseY>>1);

                drawingCanvas.graphics.setStrokeStyle(40, "round", "round")
                    .beginStroke("rgba(0,0,0,0.15)")
                    .moveTo(midPoint.x, midPoint.y)
                    .curveTo(oldPt.x, oldPt.y, oldMidPt.x, oldMidPt.y);

        oldPt.x = stage.mouseX;
        oldPt.y = stage.mouseY;

        oldMidPt.x = midPoint.x;
        oldMidPt.y = midPoint.y;

        updateCacheImage(true);

    }

    function handleMouseUp(event) {
        updateCacheImage(true);
        isDrawing = false;
    }
```

**The save function**

```
 function saveImage() {
 var canvasData = testCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
window.open(testCanvas.toDataURL("images/png"));
 var xmlHttpReq = false;       
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
     ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
 }

 else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
     ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
ajax.open('POST', 'testSave.php', false);
ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log(ajax.responseText);
 }
ajax.send("imgData="+canvasData);
}
```

Comment: I don't know about the plugin you used but if nobody can give you a solution, try [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)

Comment: Am I guessing correct, that you have placed your own cursor-image on the stage? If so, then just add this to the beginning of your `saveImage()`: `cursor.visible = false; stage.update();` - and don't forget to make your cursor visible again after the image is saved.